# Upload Audio to a URL With HttpWebRequest (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, http, curl

I am trying to upload audio to a URL in the same way that you would using a cURL command. The cURL looks like this:

```
    curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/speech' \
 -i -L \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
 -H 'Accept: application/vnd.wit.20140620+json' \
 -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" \
 --data-binary "@sample.wav"
```

Here is my current code using just plaintext URL, which works perfectly:

```
    Dim editedText As String = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "%20")
    Dim myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20140609&q=" + editedText + "&units=metric"), HttpWebRequest)
    myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer <myautcodegoeshere>")
    Dim myHttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim myWebSource As New StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim myPageSource As String = myWebSource.ReadToEnd()
    Return myPageSource
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your problem? I don't see a question.

Comment: My problem is that I cannot figure out how to upload audio to that URL. @mason

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx) that I found with less than 60 seconds of searching? Try that out, and then let us know if you have specific problems.